# Example: Push-Forward Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a continuous map, $\mathscr{F}$ a sheaf on $X$.
$f_*\mathscr{F}$ is the sheaf on $Y$ defined by $f_*\mathscr{F}(U)=\mathscr{F}(f^{-1}(U))$ Uand $\rho_{VU}=\rho_{f^{-1}(V)f^{-1}(U)}: f_*\mathscr{F}(V)\to f_*\mathscr{F}(U)$.

Example: Let $X= \{P,Q\}$ with the discrete topology and $Y=\{R\}.$ $f:X\to Y$ and let $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the sheaf of local constant real valued functions on $X$.
Then $
     f_*(\underline{\mathbb{R}})=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \mathbb{R}^2, & U=\{R\} \\
         0, & U=\emptyset\end{array}\right.$

Why do we have that $\underline{\mathbb{R}}(f^{-1}(R))= \mathbb{R}^2$?
I don't see where this comes from.

Comment: What is the space of real-valued functions on a 2-point set?

Comment: well, I might have an idea: $\underline{\mathbb{R}}(f^{-1}(R))$ are the locally constant maps $f^{-1}(R)\to\mathbb{R}$. And since we have that $P$ and $Q$ are themselves open in $X$, so the map is locally constant iff the map is constant on $P$ and $Q$. So we have all maps from $P\to\mathbb{Z}$ and $Q\to\mathbb{Z}$. So $\underline{\mathbb{R}}(f^{-1}(R))=\mathbb{R}^2$. Can I say it like that?

Comment: Dear Luca, yes, that seems like a a good way to answer (except some Z's should be R's.)

Comment: oh right. I somehow can't edit the comment any longer. but yes, the last two $\mathbb{Z}$ should be $\mathbb{R}$'s. Thanks!